# Checking if multiple file paths exist using a column range, and then writing "ok/nok"

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the scenario:

- I have a sheet which has, in column "A", a number of different folder paths
- Column A has an unknown number of rows
- A folder structure in "C:\Program Files\xxxx"
- .xls files within the folder structure "C:\Program Files\Year\Month\sheet.xls

I need a VBA script to check if
* validate if each folder path in column A is already there and then write "ok"/"nok" in column B accordingly
* validate if the .xls file within the folder structure is placed correctly

If possible, it would be better to have a Sub to validate folder structure and a second sub to validate the .xls file

Comment: Take alook at the DIR() command in VBA. It also doesnt matters if you use one sub for this simple task or 20. I would use one sub and maybe 10-20 lines of code. Wit a small bit of own afford on google you can copy and paste this together.

Comment: I'm trying vba.filesystem.dir (activecell) but its not working. Any ideas?

Comment: You should include the code you are trying to use (in your question) and explain what specific errors you are having with it and where the errors occur in your code. If you have no code at all yet, then you are not ready to be asking questions in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. It seems that you didn´t try anything. SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: If you want help her poste your code. We can not read your harddrive :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can find out if the folder structures exist. I don't have enough information to know how you might validate which workbooks should be in which folder. Hopefully this will help you get started.

You will need to go to Tools >> References and search for the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Check_Folder_Path()
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim myPath As String

    Dim oFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow

        ' Check if the path contains a file. If so, extract only the file path.
        If Right(Cells(i, 1), 3) = "xls" Or Right(Cells(i, 1), 4) = "xlsx" Then
            myPath = Left(Cells(i, 1), InStrRev(Cells(i, 1), "\"))
        Else
            ' Ensure the last character is "\"
            If Right(Cells(i, 1), 1) <> "\" Then
                myPath = Cells(i, 1) & "\"
            Else
                myPath = Cells(i, 1)
            End If
        End If

        ' Check if folder exists
        If oFSO.FolderExists(myPath) = True Then
            Cells(i, 2) = "OK"
        Else
            Cells(i, 2) = "NOK"
        End If

    Next i

    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Best of luck with your project!